# Word VBA to Delete Tables with Bookmarks

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word Document with multiple Tables. Some of them have bookmarks and the other don't. Is there a way to implement ConvertToText command ONLY on the tables with the bookmarks on them using VBA (regardless of the bookmark name....I have over 40 bookmarks)?
Basically, I'm trying to get rid of the bookmarked tables and keep just the text in those. The bookmarked tables are inserted INSIDE other tables WITHOUT bookmarks.
I'm using MS Word 2007.

Thanks in Advance!
Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is quite simple solution.
You need to loop through all bookmarks and check if one is `wdWithInTable`. If so, convert whole table into text. Here is a code for you:

```
Sub ConvertTablesWithBookmarks()


    Dim BK As Bookmark
    For Each BK In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        If BK.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            'uncomment for test just to check if working as expected
            'BK.Range.Tables(1).Select

            BK.Range.Tables(1).ConvertToText
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

---

After additional explanation in comment below there are some hints for you to solve your problem.

To find a table in which your bookmark is:

```
Activedocument.bookmarks(1).Range.Tables(1)
```

To find first table in above table you use this code

```
Activedocument.bookmarks(1).Range.Tables(1).Tables(1)
```

but I think you can have a few tables inside you parent table. Therefore i suggest to run a loop like this (pseudo code, requires some adjustment to your needs):

```
dim parentTable as Table
dim BK as Bookmark     'or a reference to one from loop above
set BK = Activedocument.bookmarks(1)
set parentTable = BK.Range.Tables(1)
dim i as integer
for i=1 to parentTable.Tables.Count
    if parenttable.tables(i).range.start >=bk.range.start and _
       parenttable.tables(i).range.end <=bk.range.end Then
       'here we know that tables(i) is inside bookmark 1 (BK)

       parenttable.tables(i).converttotext
     end if
next i
```

I didn't have an oportunity to test it but hope it will work.

Comment: Wow can't believe KazJaw is answering my question.....I've read so many of your answers for a while now and have been using them...you're so helpful!

Comment: KazJaw, just tested the above and it is deleting the "outside" nonbmtables as well. Sorry, here's my problem: 
I have a source.doc with bookmarked tables (users type inside the bookmarked tables) & target.doc. Using INCLUDETEXT command in Word, I link those bookmarked content into sections of a final template(target.doc). Problem: INCLUDETEXT brings in tables along with the content; these INCLUDETEXT fields are inserted inside other (NON-bookmarked) tables. Need to get rid of tables that come with the bookmarked content from source.doc & keep the original (non BM) tables in the target.doc.

Comment: Ok, I see it is a bit different situation to one described in your question. I can give you some hints hoping you will solve it on your own... soon in the answer...

Comment: Hi KazJaw, thanks for your prompt response! Firstly, pardon my ignorance, as you can tell, I'm a complete novice to VB (this is my first attempt). Tried the above pseudo code and it only works if the put in a specific bm name and then it deletes just that table. For example, if I replace the (1) with the actual bookmark name, it converts that particualar text (which is exactly what I want):
Set BK = ActiveDocument.bookmarks("TestResults").

Comment: Sorry, pressed Enter too soon! Now, (again, pardon my ignorance/rookie questions), how can I tell the code to look for all tables with with a bm name, without having to duplicate the above code 50 times for each bookmarked table?

Comment: KazJaw, thanks so much, you gave me the correct solution. Just learned now to use an integer to loop through all bookmarked tables and it works like a charm. I really appreciate your time and your thoughts in helping a lot of people here, God Bless you!